# Angular app 6 in ASP.NET Core: More than one module matches

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6, angular-components

**Angular v6.1.10 | ASP.NET Core v2.2.102**

I am building an Angular app from an ASP.NET Core template.

I want to create a component (fish-form).

In ASP.NET Core 2.0, a simple

```
ng g component fish-form --module=app.module.shared.ts
```

Would solve the problem, but with this architecture, as it doesn't have that file, it doesn't work.

[image: This is the files structure.]

---

I have also tried to create the component using

```
ng g component fish-form
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip
>   importing the component into the closest module.

[image: Command that I am running to create a form]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

```
ng g component fish-form --module=app.module.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. `ng g component fish-form --skipImport=true`. This will remove the error, but not import the component.
2. A better solution though `ng g component fish-form --module=app.module.ts`